# Почему не выполняется условие? Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Всем привет. Изучаю Java. *Напишите функцию, чтобы найти самую длинную строку общего префикса среди массива строк. Если такой строки нет - выведите ""*.Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не выполняется условие `if (current!=strs[j].substring(0, count))` (строка 19)
Вот код:

```
package Main;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] A = {"flower","flow","flight"};
        System.out.println(longestCommonPrefix(A));
    }
 public static String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
     String mainString = strs[0];
     String finish = "";
     String current = "";
     int count=0;
     int succes=0;
     for (int i=0;i<mainString.length();i++)
     {
         current+=mainString.charAt(i);
         count+=1;
         for (int j=1;j<strs.length;j++)
         {  
             if (current!=strs[j].substring(0, count))
             {
                 return finish;
             }                   
             else
             {
                 succes+=1;
                 if (succes==2)
                 {
                     finish=current;
                 }
             } 
         }
         succes=0;
     }
     return finish;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!current.equals(strs[j].substring(0, count)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что здесь вы сравниваете не содержимое строки, а ссылки на переменные.

```
if (current!=strs[j].substring(0, count))
```

Для сравнения содержимого ссылочных объектов необходимо использовать метод equals()

```
if (!current.equals(strs[j].substring(0, count)))
```